# Get error Changing a user's email/password in Firebase 3 for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking to catch the errors of the new methods to change email and password for Android, but I can't seem to find anything. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

The official documentation is not clear about this.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String newPassword = "SOME-SECURE-PASSWORD";

user.updatePassword(newPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callbacks use the new [`Task`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) class in Google Play services. There are two ways of catching errors with this:

1. Use `addOnCompleteListener`, check for `isSuccessful` and inspect the return of `getException` if it failed.
2. Use `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener`. The latter callback will include an `Exception` with the error.

The actual exceptions returned are documented in the reference documentation for each method. For example, [`updatePassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#exceptions_6) could fail with:

- `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` thrown if the password is not strong enough
- `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` thrown if the current user's account has been disabled, deleted, or its credentials are no longer valid
- `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException` thrown if the user's last sign-in time does not meet the security threshold. Use `reauthenticate(AuthCredential)` to resolve. This does not apply if the user is anonymous.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
But I didn't understand how to retrieve the specific exception using these methods. They only return a general exception or the message. Could you be more specific in your answer?

Comment: Couple of examples: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/firebasestorage/MainActivity.java#L200  and https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/AnonymousAuthActivity.java#L123 - does that explain a bit?

Comment: Oh - and you can compare the exception to these types, e.g 
`if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) { //... }`